# apex page scoped items

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I need to add title to several pages in apex. It has to be placed in some place on the page different from #TITLE# region, so I have changed page template and put there &MY_TEMPLATE. substitution string. On the page in computation process I fill that page item with information from database.

But problem has appeared: apex doesn't allow to have page items with the same name even if they are on different pages!

So I need something like page scoped page item that doesn't affect other pages. Or double substitution string (are there one?) to build page item name for specific page &(&APP_PAGE_ID._MY_TITLE). Or some other workaround for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think you need a page item for this, and not just an application item like `APP_PAGE_TITLE`?  Since you can only display one page at a time and you are going to populate it during page load, you don't need to "remember" the titles of other pages at the same time do you?

Comment: Yes, I don't need to remember other titles. But what if user will load several pages at the same time? Is page loading process atomic? I mean will not APP_PAGE_TITLE be changed after it is set (on some page but not yet rendered) and then it is set on the other page, so the first page will have the second page's title?

Comment: What do you mean by "load several pages at the same time"?  Do you mean they have several browser sessions, or is your application using frames to load several sub-pages?

Comment: OK, well as long as each browser has its own Apex session, you are fine: each Apex session will have its own copy of the application item.  On the other hand, if each browser window is using the **same** Apex session then you have problems with **all** your session state, not just this one!

Comment: So it is possible to corrupt this value from one session? For example user open several pages in tabs (or in different browser windows doesn't matter) with that title. This requests are not simultaneous, but very close (300 msec interval for example). Can I be sure that each page will have its own title and not other title?

Comment: As long as the user starts a fresh session (logs in again) in each tab/window then they will have a different Apex session ID in each and all will be fine.  However, if they use the browser's "open link in a new tab/window" functionality on a link then they will have 2 tabs/windows with the same Apex session ID.  Even then, since the title is both set and displayed during page load it is unlikely to matter unless they manage to load 2 pages absolutely simultaneously.  I would be more concerned about other session state, like form items.

Comment: See http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=366883&tstart=0 for a discussion of the issue I referred to in my previous comment.